# Referencing a Javascript Iterator from an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function where I need to create one anonymous functions per item in an array.  I am parsing a CSV file and I want to create an anonymous function to process each row (so I can use async.paralell).

See the following fiddle to get an idea what I am trying to do:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var func_arr = [];
var str = 'Output: ';
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var aFunc = function () {
        str = str + ' ' + i.toString();
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = str;
    }
    func_arr.push(aFunc);
}

for (var x = 0; x < func_arr.length; x++) {
    var func = func_arr[x];
    func();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tg1fpjy7/4/  (the expected output should be 1 2 3)

Here is one way I solved it using another variable to track position again : https://jsfiddle.net/pk0Lc16L/1/  ..  however, I hate the solution and there must be a more elegant way of doing this.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: If you are not against a build step, use ES6's `let` instead of `var`, it's block scoped.

Comment: My attempt at a slightly more functional approach [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/papofvnc/)

Comment: Thanks for linking the other question, it helped quite a bit.  I hate transcompiling so I am going to avoid ES6 until it is native.